# Angular component for showing all data after typing '@'

Tags: angular

I have an API for fetching data. I need an `Angular component` which will display these data after typing `'@'` at any place of `input/text field` of the form.

Need your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you need angular mention component. You can try in following way _

https://github.com/dmacfarlane/angular-mentions

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use `keyup` event for getting key code.

```
template: `
  <input (keyup)="onKey($event)">
`

  onKey(event: any) {
    if (event.target.value === '@') {
       // do some action, change visibility, and so on...
    }
  }
```

All details you can find in Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel (ngModelChange)="valuechange($event.target.value)" />
```

listen to the model change event for all inputs.

> app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';
  mymodel: any;
  captureMode: boolean;
  stringCapture: string;
  constructor() {
    this.stringCapture = "";
    this.captureMode = false;
  }
  valuechange(event: any) {
    if (this.captureMode == true) {
      if (this.captureMode == true && event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
        this.stringCapture += event.key;
        // make your api call with stringCapture
      }
      this.captureMode = true;
    }

    if (event.keyCode == 50) {
      this.captureMode = true;
      this.stringCapture = ""
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 32) {
      this.captureMode = false;
      this.stringCapture = "";
    }
  }
}
```

so i have removed the capturing on `spacebar`